# Maximum of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $p,q\in\Bbb N$ with $p\not=q$. Put $$M=\sup_{x\in[0,1]} \left|\cos(2 p\pi x)-\cos(2 q\pi x)\right|.$$
What is the value of  $M$.
Thanks

Comment: this looks like a complicated question to me --- $p=1$, $q=5$ gives $M=\frac{1}{5} \sqrt{\frac{29 \sqrt{\frac{29}{5}}}{2}+\frac{95}{2}}$ --- is there an easy way to see this?

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan is it obvious that there is a nice closed form formula for arbitrary $p$ and $q$? When $p$ and $q$ contain different powers of $2$, the answer is easy, but when they are both odd, and with the larger one being $\geq 11$, the maximum is related to the root of a polynomial of degree $\geq 5$. It is not clear to me a solution in radicals exist.

Comment: @Wikkie Wong. Yes there is probably no formula covering all cases. But, to avoid anyconfusion with homework, Zoran Vicovic should mention simple cases, e.g. p odd and q even, where the answer is immediatly 2.

Comment: If we put  $r:=p/q$ and $\tau:=2\pi q$ we can write
$M=\sup_{0\le t \le \tau}|\cos t - \cos rt|,$
that could be easier to study for *real* $r$.